# Selecting from an excel spreadsheet into SQL Server table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-express, oledb

This question has been asked before but I tried giving full admin rights to the SQL Server user on `C:\temp\` folder location (I am using Windows authentication into SQL Server Express).

So for the following code snippet:

```
Declare @strSQL as varchar(200)
declare @file as varchar(200) 

SET @file='C:\temp\file.xlsx'
SET @strSQL=N'SELECT * INTO #mytemptable FROM OPENROWSET(''Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0'', ''Excel 8.0;Database='+@file+';HDR=YES'', ''SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]'');'
SET @strSQL=@strSQL+N'SELECT * FROM ##mytemptable'
PRINT @strSQL
Exec (@strSQL)
```

EXPANDED SQL STATEMENT

```
SELECT * 
INTO #mytemptable 
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0', 'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\temp\file.xlsx;HDR=YES', 'SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$]');

SELECT * FROM ##mytemptable
```

I get this error:

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>   Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: Try running  **FileMon** when the SQL is executed. This will tell you if you have required permissions or not as described http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/23/ole-db-provider-microsoft-jet-oledb-4-0-for-linked-server-null-returned-message-unspecified-error.aspx

Comment: you appear to be writing to #mytemptable then you try to select from ##mytemptable. I guess you want ##mytemptable in both places

Comment: Is there a reason why you're using `OPENROWSET` instead of a more appropriate tool like [BCP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx), [`BULK INSERT`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx), or [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)?

Answer (score 2):

Excel is 32-bit, if you are using 64-bit version of Windows it could be causing this problem. I have 32 bit drivers installed and get the same error as you. In order to install the office 64 bit drivers would have to uninstall the 32 bit drivers first.